# Construct infinite products of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I meet a difficulty when reading R. M. Dudley's book *Real Analysis and Probability*. 
In Section 8.2 of his book, he describes a classical way to construct a countable product of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ by decimal expansions.
A detailed construction of the product measure is as follow. (page 256 of his book.)

[image]

But I don't know why the distribution of any $(y_1,\ldots, y_k)$ is Lebesgue measure on the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^k$.
Any hint or reference will be appreciated.